# How can I upload a CSV file (or similar) to an Azure Service Bus queue as messages?

Tags: powershell, csv, azure, azureservicebus

I goofed up and sent a couple hundred bad messages to my Azure Service Bus queue. There's data missing from the messages, so they're useless.

I scraped the missing data from my logs, and I have a CSV file that now contains the missing data. I'd like to upload this file as messages to my queue, but I'm having a hard time finding a tool that will do this.

I'm poking around with Service Bus Explorer, but it seems the message sending feature is meant for a single message. I can't find any documentation on the feature either (not that I expect it as it's simply a very, very useful 'sample' program).

It also seems there's no built-in way to send messages to a queue using PowerShell.

Is there a handy way to accomplish this, or am I going to have to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do this short of a quick console app... or a [ScriptCs](http://scriptcs.net/) script if you're familiar with that. I do wish there were PowerShell cmdlets for quick tasks like this, but there still aren't.